# Removing a value at a specified index of a dictionary swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, dictionary

I am writing a function that deletes a search from an apps NSUserDefaults. The method removes the deleted search from the searches Dictionary. I am confused about the syntax of this function. I don't understand how we access the value of the searches Dictionary with the searches[tags[index]]. To access the value at that index of the searches Dictionary wouldn't we just say searches[index] ?

```
private var searches: Dictionary <String, String> = [:] // stores tag-query pairs
private var tags: Array<String> = [] // stores tags in user-specified order

        // returns the query String for the taga at a given index
        func queryForTagAtIndex(index: Int) -> String? {
            return searches[tags[index]]
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your dictionary is of the `type [String:String]` to access or add a value to it, the key should be of type `String` and not `Int`. `index` is of Type `Int`. So it will give an error if we do  `return searches[index]`. And since `tags` is of type `String`, we can use that as the key for the `searches`.

Here are some links that will help you : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/Dictionary.html

And I would edit the code for readability purposes to this :

```
 private var searches:[String:String]=[String:String]() // stores tag-query pairs
 private var tags:[String] = [String]() // stores tags in user-specified order

// returns the query String for the taga at a given index
func queryForTagAtIndex(index: Int) -> String? {
   return searches[tags[index]]
}
```